# Odd 404 during URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, iis-8

Background: I'm forwarding incoming 80/443 traffic to `\\SERVER2`; TFS is running on `\\SERVER3`. I wish to route all TFS-related requests to `\\SERVER3`. I have to do it this way as I'm running Server Essentials on `\\SERVER2`, which is finicky enough to not work well under URL rewriting (almost as bad as SharePoint, but not quite).

Here's the only rule on the default website:

```
<rule name="TFS Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^tfs(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:8080/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

...and here's the Failed Request Log: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AodXF_j3BiWkhPAZwjnwC-rAecVgtw

Note the requested URL on line #87 of the PDF: `http://server3:8080/tfs`. I can browse to that internally just fine. The external URL is `https://tfs.domain.com/tfs`.

The next entry that's at all file-specific is the 404 itself, on line #165.

I just don't get this. It's a simple rule. Why would IIS turn up a 404 for a clearly valid and working URL?

**EDIT**

As a test, I added this condition:

```
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="tfs.domain.com" />
  </conditions>
```

Now if I browse to `https://tfs.domain.com/`, the default website loads.

This—together with the logs—would seem to indicate that while IIS is rewriting the URL, traffic isn't actually being routed to `\\SERVER3`.

What's going on here? This is a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working.

I'd installed both the URL Rewrite and ARR Modules, but I hadn't yet enabled proxy processing.

I created a dummy Reverse Proxy rule and was prompted to turn it on in IIS. I did so, deleted the dummy rule and now all is working as expected.